# complex query to mongodb database $eq ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi Can someone tell me why I cant $eq author with objectId?

```
db.boards.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        "boardcards": {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$lists.cards",
            initialValue: [ ],
            in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", {
            $filter: {
               input: "$$this",
               as: "result",
               cond: { "$eq": [
                      "$$result.Author",
                       ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")                    
                   ] 
                   }
            }
         } 
         ] 
         }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

If I change ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d") for "dada" and in $lists.cards is position like :

```
    "cards" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "3",
            "Author" : "dada"
        }
    ]
},
```

The query will find the result, but if i Change for ObjectID where I have:

```
 {
            "list" : "6",
            "cards" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "1"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "2"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "3",
                    "Author" : [ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Can someone tell me how to fix that,because i cant equall with objectid

Its can be by that I dont have set in model Object id??

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
var BoardSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, maxlength: 20 },
  lists : { type: Array },
  users : [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Board', BoardSchema);
```

**EDIT**
I need to make search given id in array If I have:

```
 {
            "list" : "6",
            "cards" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "1"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "2"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "3",
                    "Author" : [ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d"), ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d"), ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")                                  ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

I did like u said:

```
    db.boards.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        "boardcards": {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$lists.cards",
            initialValue: [ ],
            in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", {
            $filter: {
               input: "$$this",
               as: "result",
                   cond : { "$in": [ "$$result.Author", array ]}
            }
         } 
         ] 
         }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
    "$unwind": "$boardcards"
  } 
  ]
)
```

and is error, array is not defined

Comment: Object ids are not equal - `ObjectId("59cd1f9a71b8ad5f48eb74f6") != ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")`

Comment: sorry I make mistake,  look here is whole code https://gist.github.com/Turqus/27e3933223b340b3f8fa6ce84639d2a6 I make correct and still cant find

Comment: So what you have is both `"Author" : [ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")]` & `"Author" : ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")` right ? `$eq` will only match `ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")` not the array.

Comment: you are king ! I change for [ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")]   and now is ok. thank you very much :)!!

Comment: Hey @Veeram if I have   cond: { "$eq": [ "$$result.Author"  [ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")]  ]  }  And this $eq match only this results in which is array with only one item, How to make it search the array to find the user ??

Comment: Can you pls update the question with more details ? I'm not sure what you are asking. Try cond: { "$in": [ "$$result.Author", array ]}

Comment: hey I did editt

Comment: Sorry try  `cond: { "$in": [ replace with your  single value object id, "$$result.Author" ]}`. This will check your input object iagainst the author array.

Comment: Can u look here? https://gist.github.com/Turqus/1ac8a6d060b73178f066bc8404482bf0

Comment: Sorry I should have noted that you check for array and then do comparison.  Replace `"$$result.Author"` with `{$ifNull:["$$result.Author", []]}`. This will replace the array with [] when it is not there.

Comment: Thanks Do not think that you give the solution and I will not learn it :) It work, last question If i want make Inquiry AJAX, to node to pull data, I can make this aggregate inside function Board.FinyById()~~ ?

Comment: Np. I'm happy to help.I'm sure you are learning.  There is separate aggregate function. Try `Board.aggregate(insert aggregate query here)` Here is the link http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate

Comment: Thanks last last last question :D, If I want make function addUserToCard(idUser). The whole project is unfortunately on the arrays. So, I must push inside lists.cards.author, id user, then I have to make Inquiry AJAX to API, with Board.findOneAndUpdate and update cards ,and here is question I must somehow in model make  type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'  ?? to save _id as ObjectID ?? because i am 100% sure that at this moment it will be save like some string -> 59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d

Comment: Np. I'm not familiar with mongoose. You should consider creating a separate question for this part and someone will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using typescript, and you are getting id from params then use  new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.currentUser?.id + "")

```
offers: {
          $filter: {
            input: '$offers',
            as: 'o',
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                '$$o.user',
                new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.currentUser?.id + ""),
              ],
            },
          },
        },
```